# node install some times have @ and not always

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am new to node, and am watching videos/instructions on installations.  I see some installs have a `@`

```
npm install @babel/preset-env
```

while some don't,

```
npm install http-server
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature called ["scopes"](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-scopes).

> When you sign up for an npm user account or create an Org, you are granted a scope that matches your user or Org name. You can use this scope as a namespace for related packages.
>
> A scope allows you to create a package with the same name as a package created by another user or Org without conflict.
>
> When listed as a dependent in a `package.json` file, scoped packages are preceded by their scope name. The scope name is everything between the `@` and the slash:

Answer (score 1):

`http-server` is not a [scoped package](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope) whereas for example `@sinonjs/text-encoding` is.

> All npm packages have a name. Some package names also have a scope. A scope follows the usual rules for package names (URL-safe characters, no leading dots or underscores). When used in package names, scopes are preceded by an @ symbol and followed by a slash, e.g.

It's especially useful for companies with private repos but has gained popularity with open source in recent years.